# use nvidia-docker-compose launch a container, but exited soon

Tags: docker-compose

My `docker-compose.yml` file :

```
version: '2'
services:
  zl:
    image: zl/caffe-torch-gpu:12.27
    ports:
      - "8801:8888"
      - "6001:6008"
    devices:
      - /dev/nvidia0
    volumes:
      - ~/dl-data:/root/dl-data
```

After `nvidia-docker-compose up -d` the container launched, but exited soon.

But when I launch a container by `nvidia-docker` way, it worked well.

```
nvidia-docker run -itd -p 6008:6006 -p 8808:8888 -v `pwd`:/root/dl-data --name zl_test
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use nvidia-docker-compose. 
By configuring the nvdia-docker plugin correctly you can just use docker-compose!

Via the [nvidia docker git repo](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/39):
(can confirm it works for me)

## Step 1:

Figure out nvidia driver version (it matters). 
run:

```
 nvidia-smi
```

output:

+---------------------------------------------------------------+

NVIDIA-SMI 367.57                   Driver Version: 367.57

|-------------------------------+--------+----------------------+

## Step 2:

*create a docker volume that uses the nvidia-docker plugin must be done outside of compose as compose will mangle the volume name if it creates it.*

```
docker volume create --name=nvidia_driver_367.57 -d nvidia-docker
```

## Step 3

in the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
    volumes:
      nvidia_driver_367.57: # same name as one created above
        external: true  #this will use the volume we created above

    services:
      cuda:
        command: nvidia-smi
        devices:  #this is required
        - /dev/nvidiactl
        - /dev/nvidia-uvm
        - /dev/nvidia0 #in general: /dev/nvidia# where # depends on which gpu card is wanted to be used
        image: nvidia/cuda
        volumes:
        - nvidia_driver_367.57:/usr/local/nvidia/:ro
```

Comment: @oneklc - I know this is not from now... but maybe you can help me two... trying to use the method you wrote but I guess I'm missing something? is this the full yml file?

Comment: @boaz This is the full yml file i'm using. The key thing here is the creation of the external docker volume.   Note its docker-compose version 2 so you'll need a compatible version of docker-compose.  And Nvidia-docker needs to be installed if that wasn't clear.  Depending on the os the devices might be named differently (mine was tested on centos 7 and ubuntu 14.04).  Also i can verify this doesn't work over docker swarm, i had no luck starting GPU services remotely with this setup (well they started but didn't work).