# use nvidia-docker from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nvidia-docker

I would like to run 2 docker images with docker-compose.

one image should run with nvidia-docker and the other with docker.

I've seen this post [use nvidia-docker-compose launch a container, but exited soon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346401/use-nvidia-docker-compose-launch-a-container-but-exited-soon#comment73796775_41947086)
but this is not working for me(not even running only one image)...

any idea would be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

UPDATE : please check nvidia-docker 2 and its support of docker-compose first 
https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#do-you-support-docker-compose

(I'd first suggest adding the nvidia-docker tag).

If you look at the nvidia-docker-compose code [here](https://github.com/eywalker/nvidia-docker-compose) it only generates a specific docker-file for docker-compose after a query of the nvidia configuration on localhost:3476.

You can also make by hand this docker-compose file as they turn out to be quite simple, follow this example, replace 375.66 with your nvidia driver version and put as many /dev/nvidia[n] lines as you have graphic cards (did not try to put services on separate GPUs but go for it !):

```
services:
  exampleservice0:
    devices:
    - /dev/nvidia0
    - /dev/nvidia1
    - /dev/nvidiactl
    - /dev/nvidia-uvm
    - /dev/nvidia-uvm-tools
    environment:
    - EXAMPLE_ENV_VARIABLE=example
    image: company/image
    volumes:
    - ./disk:/disk
    - nvidia_driver_375.66:/usr/local/nvidia:ro
version: '2'
volumes:
  media: null
  nvidia_driver_375.66:
    external: true
```

Then just run this hand-made docker-compose file with a classic docker-compose command.

Maybe you can then compose with non nvidia dockers by skipping the nvidia specific stuff in the other services.

Comment: this worked for me and is absolutely the right answer. where is this documented, do you know?

Comment: Hi ! Again things should get simpler with version 2 if your usage is compatible. I worked it out from the code, but I guess for version 1.0 the best is from NVIDIA docker documentation: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/GPU-isolation-%28version-1.0%29

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to the accepted answer, here's my approach, a bit shorter.
I needed to use the old version of docker-compose (`2.3`) because of the required `runtime: nvidia` (won't necessarily work with `version: 3` - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59033632/how-can-i-specify-the-container-runtime-to-use-in-docker-compose-version-3)). Setting `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all` will make all the GPUs visible.

```yaml
version: '2.3'

services:
    your-service-name:
      runtime: nvidia
      environment:
        - NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
      # ...your stuff
```

My example is available [here](https://github.com/DominikFilipiak/ai-notebook).

Tested on NVIDIA Docker 2.5.0, Docker CE 19.03.13 and NVIDIA-SMI 418.152.00 and CUDA 10.1 on Debian 10.

Comment: According to link `Upgrade you docker-compose to 1.27.0+` resolves issue `>3`