# How can I specify the container runtime to use in docker-compose version 3?

Tags: docker-compose, nvidia-docker

I'm working on a container that requires the nvidia runtime. I can specify this runtime in a v2.3 docker-compose file like so:

```
version: "2.3"
services:
  my-service:
    image: "my-image"
    runtime: "nvidia"
    ...
```

Running `docker-compose up my-service` works just fine. I get the nvidia runtime and everything works fine.

I've tried this just by changing the "2.3" to "3" and I get the following error when I do `docker-compose up my-service`:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.my-service: 'runtime'
```

If I take out the `runtime: "nvidia"` line, this comes up without problems—except of course it's not using nvidia and I need access to the GPU on the host to get the performance I want.

Is there an equivalent for `runtime` in docker-compose v3? If not, why was this option dropped? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize this question is rather old but I ran into it yesterday.

**TL;DR :**
Upgrade you docker-compose to 1.27.0+

**Details**

There has been quite a discussion about the removal of the `runtime` keyword in the dedicated Docker bug thread : https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6691

Finally, in the 1.27.0, Docker has decided to allow it back. So you just need to have the correct version of docker-compose.

I would recommend the pip install path as their versions are more up to date (current docker-compose version in Debian buster is 1.21).
And it seems there are [other good reasons to do so, see here](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-74-curl-vs-pip-for-installing-docker-compose).